# How to check if the first entry of an array of entries is empty when the array is of type struct in C?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, struct

I have to write a Program for Uni in which there is supposed to be a queue with a priority and in the queue there is supposed to be an array of entries of which each entry needs to be 31 characters. Also there needs to be a function that checks if the queue is empty or full. I have written this code but it doesnt work, I get the error invalid oprands to binary == (have entry and 'int'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum priority {
    H, h, n, l, L      //Priority enum Highest = 0 Lowest = 4
};

typedef struct entry{
    enum priority priorityvar;
    char message[31];
} entry;

typedef struct pqueue {
    entry entries[10];
} pqueue;

int isEmpty(pqueue* pqueue){
    if (pqueue->entries[0] == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int isFull(pqueue* pqueue){
    if (pqueue->entries[9] != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I also tried to replace the 0 with a NULL but that didnt work either, I would be so grateful for any help! Thank you so much!!

Ps: I also have to write a function later in which the first entry is being printed and deleted while all the other etries move 1 "up" in the queue and I have no Idea how to implement that. If somebody has ideas thank you so much!!

Comment: You probably want the `size` to be separate from the `capacity`, (which is fixed, 10.) Not all 10 items are always full, so you have to have a `size` in your `pqueue`.

Comment: Aside: was that `return 1;` or `return l;`? Please avoid using names that look like numbers, you'll make the code harder to read, easy to confuse and make mistakes. Knowing that `l` is used in the code, every time I see a `1` I must squint carefully at it to make sure it isn't `l`, losing focus on the bigger picture.

Comment: That is return 1 (True). I understand what you are saying but unfortunately I have some variables and function names given that I am not allowed to change

Comment: The canonical implementation of a priority queue is a heap.  In fact, these terms are sometimes used interchangeably (but less so these days).

Comment: Also, C arrays are never empty.  It may be that none of their elements contain data that is significant for the program's purposes, but that's a completely different thing: the elements exist, but you want to disregard them.  To track this, you need either an external indicator of which / how many elements contain valid data, or you need the elements themselves to support a value that you can programmatically recognize as indicating "no data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pqueue` is a pointer in the function `isEmpty`, it points to an array of entries. You are accessing the array entries, when you write `pqueue->entries[0]` you are accessing the element of type `entry`, but this isn't a pointer to check if it's `NULL`! What you should do is create a variable, say next in the struct `pqueue` that tells you where the next empty spot is, give it an initial value of `-1`, and you will check if its `-1`, then your queue is empty, and so on, when adding an element increment it by 1, before adding.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot!! Just one more question, why do you recommend initialising the count variable with -1 rather than 0?

Comment: There's no reason, but since you're trying to create a queue, you'd actually need 2 variables one for the front and the other for the rear!

Comment: What do you mean by that? What front and what rear? I know implemented a queuelength variable inside of the pqueue struct. what else am i missing?